# How do I get a tab delimited MySQL dump from a remote host ?

Tags: csv, export, mysql

A mysqldump command like the following:

```
mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> -h<remote_db_host> -T<target_directory> <db_name> --fields-terminated-by=,
```

will write out two files for each table (one is the schema, the other is CSV table data). To get CSV output you must specify a target directory (with -T). When -T is passed to mysqldump, it writes the data to the filesystem of the server where mysqld is running - NOT the system where the command is issued. 
Is there an easy way to dump CSV files from a remote system ?

Note: I am familiar with using a simple mysqldump and handling the STDOUT output, but I don't know of a way to get CSV table data that way without doing some substantial parsing. In this case I will use the -X option and dump xml.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry - not yet. I think the xml option is your best bet (assuming you're using a new enough version of mysql)

Comment: I do have access to the remote host, but the SELECT INTO FILE was failing, so I ended up using this: mysql -h"host" -u"user" -p"password" -e"SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable" > /tmp/table.csv. And then from my local machine: scp my_user@remote_server:/tmp/table.csv ~/table.csv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mysql -h remote_host -e "SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table" --batch --silent > my_file.csv
```

Comment: This works great. Just note that it's tab-separated, not comma.

Comment: how do you import a batch file?

Comment: what happens when some values in some columns include tabs?  How do you get it to escape tabs and newline characters?

Comment: @Milimetric has a point, and I also want to add that it won't handle **NULL** values properly. NULL should be \N for the import but will be NULL in the file.

Comment: This exports data in format that cannot be later imported by mysql, this is not an good answer. As mentioned above NULL values are exported badly.

Comment: Amazing! So quick and simple

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to codeman's answer. It worked but needed about 30 minutes of tweaking for my needs.

My webserver uses centos 6/cpanel and the flags and sequence which codeman used above did not work for me and I had to rearrange and use different flags, etc.

Also, I used this for a local file dump, its not just useful for remote DBs, because I had too many issues with selinux and mysql user permissions for SELECT INTO OUTFILE commands, etc.

#### What worked on my Centos+Cpanel Server

```
mysql -B -s -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD < query.sql > /path/to/myfile.txt
```

#### Caveats

***No Column Names***

I cant get column names to appear at the top. I tried adding the flag:

```
--column-names
```

but it made no difference. I am still stuck on this one. I currently add it to the file after processing.

***Selecting a Database***

For some reason, I couldn't include the database name in the commandline. I tried with

```
-D databasename
```

in the commandline but I kept getting permission errors, so I ended using the following the top of my query.sql:

```
USE database_name;
```

Comment: try eliminating the -s for column names, from mysql --help it is redundant with -B, but on my system it made a difference

Answer (score 1):

On many systems, MySQL runs as a distinct user (such as user "mysql") and your mysqldump will fail if the MySQL user does not have write permissions in the dump directory - it doesn't matter what your own write permissions are in that directory.  Changing your directory (at least temporarily) to world-writable (777) will often fix your export problem.